# How I can pass data of methods to others using oop, for example with numerical methods in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, oop, numerical-methods

This error appears, ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. I did it without oop and work it nice. I need the data of def loop(self): to pass it to the def f(self, x, y): and keeping the secuence

```
class rungekuta():

   def __init__(self):

      self.x = np.linspace(1, 5, 50)
      self.y = np.zeros(len(self.x))
      self.y[0] = 4
      self.loop()
      self.f()

  def f(self, x, y):

      return (self.x*np.sqrt(self.y))

  def loop(self):
      h = 0.2
      for i in range(len(self.x) - 1):
          k1 = self.f(self.x[i], self.y[i])
          k2 = self.f(self.x[i] + h / 2, self.y[i] + k1 * (h / 2))
          k3 = self.f(self.x[i] + h / 2, self.y[i] + k2 * (h / 2))
          k4 = self.f(self.x[i] + h, self.y[i] + k3 * h)
          self.y[i+1] = self.y[i]+(h / 6) * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4)

  def draw(self):
     plt.plot(self.x, self.y)
     plt.show()

run = rungekuta()
run.draw()
```

This is the algorith without opp python

```
 def f(x,y):

    return (x*np.sqrt(y))

 def rk4(f,a,b,y0,h):

    x=np.arange(a,b,h)
    n=len(x)
    k1=np.zeros(len(x))
    k2=np.zeros(len(x))
    k3=np.zeros(len(x))
    k4=np.zeros(len(x))
    y=np.zeros(len(x))
    y[0]=y0
    for i in range(0,len(x)-1):
    
        k1[i]=f(x[i],y[i])
        k2[i]=f(x[i]+h/2,y[i]+k1[i]*(h/2))
        k3[i]=f(x[i]+h/2,y[i]+k2[i]*(h/2))
        k4[i]=f(x[i]+h,y[i]+k3[i]*h)
        y[i+1]=y[i]+(h/6)*(k1[i]+2*k2[i]+2*k3[i]+k4[i])
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
rk4(f,1,5,4,0.2)
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: In the original version you're assigning to `k1[i]`, but in the OO version you're assigning to `k1`. Why did you make that change?

Comment: The second I worked with k[i] and k, it ran nice, but changing in oop to appears this error "self.y[i+1] = self.y[i]+(h / 6) * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.", I need that it worked using oop like second algorithm

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: get line which makes problem and split calculation into few shorter calculations to see which part makes problem. And use `print()` to see what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`

Comment: your `f(self, x, y)` in class is wrong - it gets `x` and `y` and you should use `x`, `y`, not `self.x`, `self.y`

Answer (score 2):

All problem is method `f()` in class. It gets `x`, `y` and it should use `x`, `y`, not `self.x`, `self.y`.

And you should remove `self.f()` from `__init__`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Rungekuta():  # PEP8: `CamerCaseNames` for classes

  def __init__(self):

      self.x = np.linspace(1, 5, 50)
      self.y = np.zeros(len(self.x))
      self.y[0] = 4
      self.loop()

  def f(self, x, y):
      return (x * np.sqrt(y))

  def loop(self):
      h = 0.2
      for i in range(len(self.x) - 1):
          k1 = self.f(self.x[i], self.y[i])
          k2 = self.f(self.x[i] + h / 2, self.y[i] + k1 * (h / 2))
          k3 = self.f(self.x[i] + h / 2, self.y[i] + k2 * (h / 2))
          k4 = self.f(self.x[i] + h, self.y[i] + k3 * h)
          self.y[i+1] = self.y[i]+(h / 6) * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4)

  def draw(self):
     plt.plot(self.x, self.y)
     plt.show()

run = Rungekuta()
run.draw()
```

---

[PEP 8 --- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)